# Collectd Exec plugin and digitemp

Tags: bash, shell, plugins, exec, collectd

I am running this script by collectd Exec plugin:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME="${COLLECTD_HOSTNAME:-`hostname -f`}"
INTERVAL="${COLLECTD_INTERVAL:-15}"

while sleep "$INTERVAL"
do
        TEMP=$(cat /home/anon/dt/temp-Sauna)
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
                TEMP="U"
        fi
        echo "PUTVAL $HOSTNAME/digitempo/Sauna interval=$INTERVAL N:$TEMP"
        TEMP=$(cat /home/anon/dt/temp-Ulko)
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
                TEMP="U"
        fi
        echo "PUTVAL $HOSTNAME/digitempo/Ulko interval=$INTERVAL N:$TEMP"

done
```

Files temp-Sauna and temp-Ulko has temperature value, like 12.33.
When i restart collectd Exec plugin enabled, it starts normally, syslog does not have any errors, but collectd is not generating new RRD files for digitempo/Ulko or digitempo/Sauna.

So any idea what might be wrong on my script?

The way i am running this script with Exec plugin is: Exec "anon:dialout" "sh" "/home/anon/lampo.sh"

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your script does not provide a correct value type.

Following the recommendation from [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1479963&p=9511593#post9511593), your values should be something like:

- `$HOSTNAME/digitempo/temperature-Sauna` and
- `$HOSTNAME/digitempo/temperature-Ulko`

This will make sure the `temperature` type from `/usr/share/collectd/types.db` will be used.